# Showing only part of Canvas in WPF C#

Tags: wpf, resize, wpf-controls, clip

I have Canvas in WPF project defined to be 1000 x 3000px.

Now i'm using Clip method from point (0,1000) to (1000, 2000).
It will be middle of that canvas.
Now i want to show it in a ScrollViewer, but there is a problem - i have a lot of space before and after that clipped part. How to align that clipped canvas to top?

More specific: Canvas contain 3 pages (1000x1000px), now i want to clip that middle page and operate on it. But in my project i want to show one page at the top op scrollviewer. After clipping i get correct part of canvas, but with spaces before and after.

How to do it? Maybe i need to use another method instead of Clip?

Or maybe something else? For example to split that canvas after every 1000px.. Like in word :)

Comment: Why don't you put each page separately into the ScrollViewer?

Comment: is there any option to show that canvas like i want without scrollviewer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with. All you have to do is replace my canvas with yours.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:AllNoneCheckboxConverter x:Key="converter"/>
        <local:ValuePointConverter x:Key="VPConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      Width="1000" Height="1000"
                      >
            <Canvas Width="3000" Height="1000">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.3"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.6"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Is there something about my answer that is unsatisfactory? I have no problem improving it but I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks user1489726 for that answer, it's good, but when i try to scroll page i can see part of first page and part of another, and i don't want that.. how to fix that?

Comment: and another thing, i have second scrollviewer outside this one to control that page (not fitting in window). and now i have also problem with scrolling becouse i'm scrolling that scrollviewer which showing that one page..

Comment: It seems like a scrollviewer probably isn't the best solution to the problem. Have you considered using buttons to switch pages? I did some googling and I didn't find any solutions to a 'snapping' scrollviewer in WPF

Comment: i found clip method to Canvas. But this one "mask" all content outside and as i said - when i try to clip 2nd page, in window there is empty space before (it looks like there should be 1st page but it is "switched off").. So maybe there is an option to clip and "align to top"?

Comment: Can you post some code? I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve. I think the easiest solution is to create two buttons and overlay the three pages. Set Visibility="Hidden" for two of the pages, then when the user clicks a button, change the visibilities accordingly